# C++ socket multi client connect

Tags: c++, sockets

I write a Server which uses epoll in Linux, and I want to test how many connect it can accept in real environment. So I write a client  in Windows, the client create many sockets to connect the remote server. So there is the question, after the server accept about 1700 connections, the new socket that client create fail to connect the server and the error code is 10060. I copy the client to another Windows and run client at 2 PC at the same time, and both of them get the same result. So, the server can accept 3400 connections about. The problems may take place In windows, and I tied to fix it：

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]
>
> MaxUserPort = 65534 (Decimal)
>
> MaxHashTableSize = 65536 (Decimal)
>
> MaxFreeTcbs = 16000 (Decimal)

But it doesn't help。
There is my Server code:

```
bool GateServer::Init(std::string &port)
{
    printf("Init to port %s\n", port.c_str());

    m_nConnNum = 0;

    m_socketfd = CreateAndBindSocket(port);

    if (m_socketfd == -1)
    {
        abort();
    }

    int result = MakeSocketNonblocking(m_socketfd);

    if (result == -1)
    {
        abort();
    }


    int z;
    int sndbuf = 0;        /* Send buffer size */
    int rcvbuf = 0;        /* Receive buffer size */
    socklen_t optlen;        /* Option length */


    /*
    * Get socket option SO_SNDBUF:
    */
    optlen = sizeof sndbuf;
    z = getsockopt(m_socketfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &sndbuf, &optlen);

    /*
    * Get socket option SON_RCVBUF:
    */

    optlen = sizeof rcvbuf;
    z = getsockopt(m_socketfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &rcvbuf, &optlen);

    /*
    * Report the buffer sizes:
    */
    printf("Send buf: %d bytes\n", sndbuf);
    printf("Recv buf: %d bytes\n", rcvbuf);



    
    m_epollfd = epoll_create1(0);
    if (m_epollfd == -1)
    {
        perror("epoll_create");
        abort();
    }

    result = listen(m_socketfd, SOMAXCONN);
    if (result == -1)
    {
        perror("listen");
        abort();
    }

    return true;
}

void GateServer::Run()
{
    int result = 0;

    struct epoll_event events[MAXEVENTS];

    result = AddEpollEvent(m_epollfd, m_socketfd, EPOLLIN | EPOLLET);//读入,边缘触发方式 
    if (result == -1)
    {
        perror("epoll_ctl");
        abort();
    }

    /* The event loop */
    while (1)
    {
        int n, i;
        n = epoll_wait(m_epollfd, events, MAXEVENTS, -1);
        HandleEvents(m_epollfd, events, n, m_socketfd);
    }

    close(m_socketfd);

}

void GateServer::HandleEvents(int epollfd, struct epoll_event *events, int num, int listenfd)
{
    int i;
    int fd;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        fd = events[i].data.fd;

        if ((events[i].events & EPOLLERR) ||
            (events[i].events & EPOLLHUP))
        {
            /* An error has occured on this fd, or the socket is not
            ready for reading (why were we notified then?) */

            fprintf(stderr, "epoll error\n");
            printf("events = %d\n", events[i].events);
            close(fd);
            m_nConnNum--;
            std::cout << "client " << fd << " disconnect. client num = " << m_nConnNum << std::endl;

            continue;
        }
        else if (fd == listenfd && (events[i].events & EPOLLIN))
        {
        /* We have a notification on the listening socket, which
                means one or more incoming connections. */
            HandleAccept(epollfd, listenfd);

        }
        else if(events[i].events & EPOLLIN)
        {
        /* We have data on the fd waiting to be read. Read and
                display it. We must read whatever data is available
                completely, as we are running in edge-triggered mode
                and won't get a notification again for the same
                data. */

            HandleRead(epollfd, fd);
        }
        else if (events[i].events & EPOLLOUT)
        {

        }
    }
}

void GateServer::HandleAccept(int epollfd, int listenfd)
{
    std::cout << "At HandleAccept." << std::endl;
    int result;
    while (1)
    {
        struct sockaddr cliaddr;
        socklen_t cliaddrlen;
        int clifd;
        char hbuf[NI_MAXHOST], sbuf[NI_MAXSERV];

        cliaddrlen = sizeof cliaddr;
        clifd = accept(listenfd, &cliaddr, &cliaddrlen);

        if (clifd == -1)
        {
            if ((errno == EAGAIN) ||
                (errno == EWOULDBLOCK))
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                perror("accept");
                break;
            }
        }

        m_nConnNum++;
        cout << "connected num = " << m_nConnNum << endl;

        result = getnameinfo(&cliaddr, cliaddrlen,
            hbuf, sizeof hbuf,
            sbuf, sizeof sbuf,
            NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);

        if (result == 0)
        {
//          printf("Accepted connection on descriptor %d "
//              "(host=%s, port=%s)\n", clifd, hbuf, sbuf);
        }



        /* Make the incoming socket non-blocking and add it to the
        list of fds to monitor. */
        result = MakeSocketNonblocking(clifd);
        if (result == -1)
        {
            abort();
        }

        result = AddEpollEvent(epollfd, clifd, EPOLLIN | EPOLLET);
        if (result == -1)
        {
            perror("epoll_ctl");
            abort();
        }
    }
}

void GateServer::HandleRead(int epollfd, int fd)
{
    //std::cout << "At HandleRead." << std::endl;
    //int done = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        ssize_t count;
        char buf[512];
        count = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));

        if (count == -1)
        {
            /* If errno == EAGAIN, that means we have read all
            data. So go back to the main loop. */
            if (errno != EAGAIN)
            {
                perror("read");
                //done = 1;
            }
            break;
        }
        else if (count == 0)
        {
            /* End of file. The remote has closed the
            connection. */
            //done = 1;
            if (m_nConnNum <= 0)
            {
                perror("close");
                abort();
            }

            cout << "client = " << fd << " disconnect." << endl;
            close(fd);
            m_nConnNum--;

            break;
        }
        //std::cout << "server rec : " << buf << std::endl;

        /* Write the buffer to standard output */
        int result = write(fd, buf, count);

        if (result == -1)
        {
            perror("write");
            abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not sound like a coding problem, or is it?

Comment: So which type that it is look like ?

Comment: It isn't clear which if any of those registry settings would have any effect on your problem. It would be more interesting to see your code, and specifically the server code.

Comment: You client is limited to opening more than 1700 socket due to some system settings -- on linux that would be `ulimit`, no idea what it is on windows.   You could probably test that by running two instances on the same machine.  Anyhow, this is a system settings issue and there are other stackexchange sites that deals with that, and stackoverflow is for programmin issues

Comment: Which version of Windows?  The optimized socket stack is likely going to be on Windows Server versions.  Also, the fact that you are using Cygwin to run Linux code on Windows creates an unnecessary abstraction. Have you considered just writing Win32 socket code and using IOCP ?

Comment: Posting part of your server code doesn't constitute posting your server code.

Comment: Look also into [0mq](http://zeromq.org/). It probably is simpler for your case.

Comment: I run server on Linux(CentOS release 6.5 (Final)), and run the client on Win7 and Win10.  And is it necessary to use IOCP to write a client?

Answer (score 0):

Your findings don't show that you've reached a server limit of any kind. They expose *client* limits of 1700 connections each. Keep testing, with more client hosts.

Comment: You are right, but I don't have more client hosts.So I wonder if it is possible to test with 2 PC.